# Horizontal/Vertical Scrolling on ListView

Tags: android, listview, scroll, tablet

I'm new to Android and I'm building an application which uses ListViews.
A ListView contains elements such as video, sound, images etc etc...
My issue is, horizontal and vertical scrolling for the tablet running 3.0

Every scroll (wether horizontal or vertical) should make a new view with other content.
I've seen this on the iPad version before but I don't know how to make it on Android.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a class on the web which created a groupview and implements horizontal paging. It also snaps on the selected page and covers the entire screen. Now I just need to find how to implement vertical paging!

Comment: what class is it that you found?